# How to handle command line arguments in C++ that has negative sign (-) in linux terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, parsing, command-line, command-line-arguments

I need this for an assignment. I know how standard command line input works in C++. if I have an executable named training, then I can write the following line in terminal:

```
./training input.text output1 output2
```

In that case my main method, would be like following:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
     take_input( argv[1] );
     make_output( argv[2], argv[3] );
}
```

And my function declarations would be following:

```
int take_input( string filename );
int make_output( string filename, string filename2 )
```

However, I need to write the command line as follows:

```
training -i input.csv -os output1 -oh output2
```

I do not know how to make the modifications. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Look up `getopt`, it's a library that is already built in in the GNU compiler.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#Example_1_(using_POSIX_standard_getopt)

Answer (score 2):

`getopt()` will work, but if your needs are minimal and you don't want to add an external dependency, you can write your own little helper function to find where the dash-keywords are inside the `argv` array, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Returns the index of the specified keyword (e.g. "-oh")
// or returns -1 if the keyword doesn't exist
static int find_keyword(int argc, char *argv[], const char * keyword)
{
   for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
   {
      if (strcmp(argv[i], keyword) == 0) return i;
   }
   return -1;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   const int iIndex = find_keyword(argc, argv, "-i");
   if (iIndex < 0) {printf("No -i keyword found!  Exiting!\n"); exit(10);}

   const int osIndex = find_keyword(argc, argv, "-os");
   if (osIndex < 0) {printf("No -os keyword found!  Exiting!\n"); exit(10);}

   const int ohIndex = find_keyword(argc, argv, "-oh");
   if (ohIndex < 0) {printf("No -oh keyword found!  Exiting!\n"); exit(10);}

   take_input( argv[iIndex+1] );
   make_output( argv[osIndex+1], argv[ohIndex+1] );
}
```

Note that the program as shown doesn't check to see if the next argument after the dash-argument exists; e.g. if you ran "./a.out -i foo -os bar -oh", then make_output's second argument would be passed in as NULL.  You could modify `find_keyword()` to check for that possibility and return -1 in that case if you wanted to be extra-robust in your error-handling.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy, that was so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you just include `unistd.h` and use [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html).

Comment: If anybody could provide the modification, that would be helpful, I am learning the get opt though.